# Setting command button visibility in VC++ 6.0?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, visual-c++-6

How can I make the command button in my VC++ 6.0 dialog visible or invisible on load?

Comment: This is not very clear. Are you talking about the command _menu_ or a button on the dialog box itself?

Answer (score 3):

From the resource editor once you select the button, you can see its properties in the properties window. Here you can set the visible property to true / false. (assuming this functionality is present in 6.0 - i use 2003 now and cannot remember if this used to be present in 6.0)

**Add CButton variable**

If you want to dynamically change the buttons visibility during load, add a variable for your button using the MFC class wizard. (you are lucky to have this - this wizard seems to have been removed from Visual Studio .NET)

**Override CDialog InitDialog**

Next override the initdialog function of your dialog box and then once the base InitDialog function has been successfully called, set the buttons showwindow property to SW_HIDE /  before showing the dialog box.

**Code**

```
BOOL CMyDialog::OnInitDialog() 
   {
   CDialog::OnInitDialog();

   if (ConditionShow)
       m_MyButton.ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
   else
       m_MyButton.ShowWindow(SW_HIDE);

   return TRUE;
   }
```

Comment: const int cmdShow = ConditionShow ? SW_SHOW : SW_HIDE;
m_MyButton.ShowWindow(cmdShow);

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it without adding a CButton variable - just call

In the OnInitDialog method of the window containing the button/control, put in code:

CWnd *wnd = GetDlgItem (YOUR_RESOURCE_NAME_OF_THE_BUTTON)
wnd->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW) or SW_HIDE

Comment: Even shorter: `GetDlgItem(IDC_MY_CTRL)->ShowWindow(SW_HIDE);`

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by 'commnad button' exactly ?

Anyway, you need to obtain the handle of the button then call ShowWindow function:

```
BOOL prevState = ShowWindow( itemHandle, SW_HIDE );
```

Comment: Cannot resolve that method. Pls post the docs if you really think that it exists – OneWorld just now

Answer (score 1):

Only use

```
ShowDlgItem(Your_DLG_ITEM_ID,1); // visible = true   
ShowDlgItem(Your_DLG_ITEM_ID,0); // visible = false
```

Comment: Cannot resolve that method. Pls post the docs if you really think that it exists